# Color filters that correspond to Macbeth chart colors

Tags: filters, color

I'm curious if anyone knows of a set of color filters that correspond to the standard Macbeth chart colors.

In theory I should be able to use a filter with a transmission spectra curve identical to the reflection curve of a Macbeth chip, point at a flat white target like a Spectralon target, and read the same rgb histograms that I would from the chip.

Just an idea I'd like to try out.

Comment: _In theory I should be able to use a filter with a transmission spectra curve identical to the reflection curve of a Macbeth chip_... The difference between theory and practice is that in theory, there is no difference between theory and practice. Meaning, transmission spectra and reflection spectra will never be the same.

Comment: *"Is this a dagger ( filter ) which I see before me, 
This handle toward my hand? Come, let me clutch thee. 
I have thee not, and yet I see thee still. 
Art thou not, fatal vision, sensible
To feeling as to sight? Or art thou but 
A dagger ( filter ) of the mind, a false creation, 
Proceeding from the heat-oppressèd brain?"*   **The Bard, Macbeth**.

Comment: @AlaskaMan make that an answer so I can upvote it. :-D

Comment: @Hueco  Done, all though it is Technically *not* an answer.

Comment: What photographic problem are you trying to solve? Why do you think this would be a solution to that problem?

Comment: Ha @AlaskaMan! It's just a thought experiment. Curious if the filters exist.

Answer (score 1):

*Now appearing by special request, a comment in the answer box* !

"Is this a dagger ( filter ) which I see before me,  This handle toward my hand? Come, let me clutch thee.

I have thee not, and yet I see thee still.

Art thou not, fatal vision, sensible To feeling as to sight? Or art thou but A dagger ( filter ) of the mind, a false creation, Proceeding from the heat-oppressèd brain?"

**The Bard, Macbeth.**

Quips from the "frozen-addled" brain of Alaska Man.

Comment: Probably the most eloquent frame challenge to a question I've ever read.

Comment: @Hueco  "To be ( a color chart ), or not to be ( a color chart ): that is the question. -   or is that the question? "What light through yonder  window breaks" and how should i set my white balance? somebody stop me. Please.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to choose filters unless one knows the spectrum of the illuminant